# find the total of five days group with irregular intervals. with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

dummy table

```
days| val
-----------
1   | 1
-----------
2   | 3
-----------
4   | 2
-----------
5   | 1
-----------
6   | 6
-----------
8   | 2
-----------
11  | 5
-----------
12  | 4
-----------
```

we want to find sum `val` column of next consecutive 5 days

Expected result

```
days| val   | tot
-----------------
1   | 1     | 7
-----------------
2   | 3     | 12
-----------------
4   | 2     | 11
-----------------
5   | 1     | 9
-----------------
6   | 6     | 8
-----------------
8   | 2     | 11    
-----------------
11  | 5     | 9
-----------------
12  | 4     | 4 
-----------------
```

I tried writing window function with frame clause but the rows option takes offset with no of rows but wants the offset with the value of days.
it might be possible with range option of frame clause but SQLITE gives only unbounded and current row as the option, not custom

not able to find an alternative.
any hint or solution will help.

what i tried

`select 
      days,val,sum(val) over ( order by days rows between current row and 5 following) tot
from
     table_name`

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Trivial to do with a pretty recent version of sqlite (3.28 or newer) using a [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) with a range [frame specification](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#frame_specifications):

```
SELECT days, val
     , sum(val) OVER (ORDER BY days RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) AS tot
FROM dummy
ORDER BY days;
```

gives

```
days        val         tot       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           7         
2           3           12        
4           2           11        
5           1           9         
6           6           8         
8           2           11        
11          5           9         
12          4           4
```

---

See [db fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q4ddUyR5NzJ39opQuPURJE/0).